# Bash script, find all the files in current folder that contains specific string

Tags: bash

so i have a line of code like:

```
list=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$1" -print0 | sed 's,\.\/,,g')
echo $list
```

so in terminal when i do `bash script_name string`

i hope it will display all the files that contain "string"

Now in a folder i have 4 matches : TesT1.c TesT1.h TesT2.c TesT2.h

when i do

```
bash script_name TesT*
```

my code only return the first match ,which is TesT1.c

Where did i do wrong, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `bash script_name TesT*` your current shell expands the glob so your run command is actually `bash script_name TesT1.c TesT1.h TesT2.c TesT2.h`.

Your script then uses `$1` (the first argument) and runs

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "TesT1.c" -print0 | sed 's,\.\/,,g'
```

which obviously only finds itself.

Quote the glob on the initial command line.

```
bash script_name 'TesT*'
```

Also there's no reason to stuff the output from `find` into a variable and then echo it back out like that.

Comment: Hi, what can i do to my script to make it work?  I don't want to quote in terminal command. :)  But thank you for helping me.

Comment: The only way to get this to work from the command line without quoting is to disable pathname expansion with `set -f`. So `set -f; bash script_name TesT*; set +f` (also a shell function is likely better for this than a separate script).

Comment: This is one of the assignment and i need to write it in a shell script lol. Anyway i think i need to find a better way to do this

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
bash script_name TesT*
```

bash expands `TesT*` at the time of calling your script and makes it:

```
bash script_name TesT1.c TesT1.h TesT2.c TesT2.h
```

Since you're only using `$1` you just get: `TesT1.c`

You need to call you script as

```
bash script_name 'TesT*'
```

to avoid expansion of glob pattern (due to use of single quote)

Comment: Hi is there any other way i  can make it work instead of quoting in terminal? like can i do sth to my script?

Comment: Another way is to just call it as: `bash script_name TesT` and then use find command as: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$1*"`